# Hosting vuejs spa without nginx or apache in docker

Tags: docker, vue.js, digital-ocean

In official vuejs docs it has a simple example of dockerizing a spa.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/dockerize-vuejs-app.html#Simple-Example

And it says it will run on `localhost:8080`

Instead of `localhost:8080` can we bind to a domain name and run?
Is this possible without nginx or apache?

Comment: What do you mean by _"bind to a domain name"_? If you want to serve anything over HTTP, you need an HTTP server

Comment: @Phil in this doc's example it uses http-server npm. With that server can I host my project with a domain name?

Comment: Yes (though I honestly wouldn't use a JS HTTP server in production). You would just need some kind of service provider to deploy your container to

Answer (score 1):

I know you didn't ask it, but I will tell my own method. Maybe it helps you

My Vuejs run localhost:8080 but i am using domain for access like sample www.myvueprojectfromlocalhost.com

Firstly I use "vue.config.js" file;

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    // setting host should not be necessary
    // host: '0.0.0.0:8080'
    public: '0.0.0.0',
    disableHostCheck: true,
  }
 }
```

Then Apache VirtualHost with ProxyPass;

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myvueprojectfromlocalhost.com

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```